# Regular expressions REGEX 4 digits PIN code with at least one different than others

Tags: regex

I tried different regex which I found here but they are not working.

for example:

```
1111 = false
1112 = true
```

It's my homework so I must do it in regex :)

Comment: only 1112 valid or other´s, too? (ex. 1113 = true, 1117 = true,...)=

Comment: True -  every 4 code pin where at least one is different 

False - 1111,2222,...,9999

Comment: I think you would need non fixed width lookbehinds to do this.  I don't even know of an online tool which supports that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{3}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Match line start
- `(\d)` - match first digit and capture it in back reference #1 i.e. `\1`
- `(?!..)` is a negative lookahead
- `(?!\1+$)` means disallow the match if first digit is followed by same digit (captured group) till end.
- `\d{3}$` match next 3 digit followed by line end

Comment: That's really good... nice one! Shorter than the one I had proposed, as it does not have a separate step for insisting that the match consists of 4 digits.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
(?=^\d{4}$)(\d)+(?!\1)\d\d*
```

The first look-ahead group `(?=^\d{4}$)` insists that the whole string consists of  4 digits.

The first capture group then matches any number of digits: `(\d)+`.

After this, there must be a digit is different to the first capture group: `(?!\1)\d`

Finally, there can be any number of digits trailing: `\d*`